# How to get the real time course details while a course is created or updated in canvas to my application?

Tags: canvas, canvas-lms, lms

I have a canvas LMS and a web application. I must copy the courses created/updated in Canvas to my application. is there any solution?

What I found was that the data service was deprecated on December 31st